# Force qsub (PBS) to wait the job's end before exiting

Tags: pbs, qsub

I've been using Sun Grid Engine to run my jobs on a node of a cluster.

Usually I would wait for the job to complete before exiting and I use:

```
qsub -sync yes perl Script.pl
```

However now I don't use anymore Sun Grid Engine but PBS Pro 10.4

I'm not able to find a corresponding instruction to -sync.

Could someone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What you ask is not standard. We need more background information to provide you with an answer !

Answer (score 0):

PBSPro doesn't have a -sync equivalent but you might be able to use the 
-I option combined with the use of expect to tell it what code to run in order to get the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of `-sync` for PBS is `-Wblock=true`.

This prevents qsub from exiting until the job has completed.  It is perhaps unusual to need this, but I found it useful when using some software that was not designed for HPC.  The software executes multiple instances of a worker program, which run simultaneously.  However, it then has to wait for one (or sometimes more) of the instances to complete, and do some work with the results, before spawning the next.  If the worker program completes without writing a particular file, it is assumed to have failed.  I was able to write a wrapper script for the worker program, to `qsub` it, and used the `-Wblock=true` option to make it wait for the worker program job to complete.